# pyaudio throwing "shared memfd open() failed" error when initialized

Tags: python, c, audio, embedded-linux, odroid

I am using `pyaudio` but I got some `error`

```
import pyaudio
 p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
```

This is my error

```
shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused
```

Any help please

Comment: I've got the exact same error message on my odroid u3 with ubuntu 18.04 trying to use vlc: `shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a headless linux-subsystem, which doesn't provide a connection to a PulseAudio server by default. (That's why you get this **connection** error.)

You have to setup a connection yourself (via tcp for example). This [is discussed here](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/5lhycw/pianobar_on_wsl_using_pulseaudio/dj73gjf/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) [and here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/486#issuecomment-299682364).